# 'ascii' codec error in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup for scraping data from the html page. Till yesterday every thing was fine. But Now i am getting the error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 86700: ordinal not in range(128)
```

i am using the code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

This is giving me the error.

Answer (score 2):

A wild guess:

Try specifying the encoding of the page?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, fromEncoding=<encoding of the page>)
```

This can also be a problem with the Python installation. If you print non-ASCII characters without BeautifulSoup, do you face the same problem? If yes, then you need to set the encoding:

```
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") # or whatever you want the default encoding to be.
```

Comment: you need `reload(sys)` due to `sys.setdefaultencoding()` is deleted in site.py as a rule.

Comment: still not working, soup = BeautifulSoup(page, fromEncoding="utf-8") giving me the same error. sys has no attribut setdefaultencoding as my interpretor is saying.

Comment: There is no python installation issue. I checked it.

Comment: What does 'sys.getdefaultencoding()' return?

Comment: ascii is return by the sys.getdefaultencoding()

Comment: Follow J. F. Sebastian's reply and try it.

Comment: well. I figure it out. It was the BeautifulSoap problem. BeautifulSoap documnetation itself suggest that it has some bug. So, I downgraded to 3.0.7 and it is woking fine.Thanx for your suggestion. +1

Answer (score 0):

A wild stab in the dark: you're reading a page that doesn't explicitly declare an encoding and yet is not 7-bit ASCII?