# BeautifulSoup find href with special characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I try to find a link with the text "next >" like:

```
next = soup.find('a', href=True, text='next ›')
print next['href']
```

But with ">" I getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x9b'
```

How to parse special characters?

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, you are aware that the character you are searching on "›" and ">" are not the same? ">" should be an ASCII character

Comment: It appears to work here with Python 3 - https://repl.it/F10b

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725823/how-to-parse-html-with-non-ascii-characters-using-beautifulsoup might be useful

Comment: post html code or url